# could $e$ in exponential distribution be replaced with other value?

Tags: arithmetic

I'm currently learning exponential distribution in class, and i have this random thought on my mind.

so, as we know, the probability density function of exponential distribution is $f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x} $ for $x>0$

and as we know too, $e$ is a constant approximately equal to $2.71828$

I wonder if $e$ in exponential distribution can be replaced by other values or positive constants, let's say by $1.5$ or $2.3$ etc?

If this happen, would it still be categorized as an exponential distribution? and would it still have its (exponential distribution's) property?

Sorry if this question is absurd and doesn't make senses, but I'm curious and haven't found the answer by myself.

Comment: Do you know the property $$a^x=e^{\log(a)x}$$

Comment: yes, im sorry but what is the correlation between this statement with the PDF of exponential distribution? if we substitue $a^{x}$ to $f_X(x)$ isn't it going to have a different value? @Xi'an

Comment: The point is that you’ve now established the proportionality. You have a “unit conversion” between e and a.

Comment: As pointed out by @AryaMcCarthy, if a probability density is such that$$f(x)\propto a^{-\lambda x}$$ it is an Exponential density with rate $\lambda\log(a)$, assuming $a>1$.

Answer (score 4):

Collecting the comments from Arya McCarthy and Xi'an together into an answer:

An elementary identity is

$$
a ^ x = \exp(\log(a) x)
$$

which establishes a "unit conversion" between $\mathcal{e}$ and $a$. So if a probability distribution has density

$$
f(x) \propto a^{-\lambda x}
$$

then it is an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda \log(a)$ for all $a > 1$.

If you seek further proof, one path is to show that the CDFs are identical.